# Error trying to call for raster file in gdb RasterToPolygon

Tags: arcpy, raster, error-000865

I'm trying to convert raster to polygon. But I'm running into error.

```
ERROR 000865: Input raster: C:/Juivy//python/python.gdb/test does not exist..
```

This is what I wrote:

```
import arcpy
workspace = "C:/Juivy/python/python.gdb"
fc = "test"
output = fc + "_" + "convert.shp"
input = workspace +"/"+ fc
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(input,output,"NO_SIMPLIFY","VALUE")
```

Comment: The rest of the code looks OK, so that error message seems to indicate that `fc` really does not exist. Try running `arcpy.Exists(input)` to verify this.

Comment: Could also be you are trying to write a Shapefile to a default gdb workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the two comments.

The error seems to be telling you that the feature class called `C:/Juivy/python/python.gdb/test` does not exist.  To cross-check whether it does you could try using:

```
print input
print arcpy.Exists(input)
```

When you get past this error I think you will encounter another because you are trying to write a shapefile into a folder (`C:/Juivy/python/python.gdb`) which is a file geodatabase.

As a test try replacing:

```
output = fc + "_" + "convert.shp"
```

with:

```
output = "C:/Juivy/python/" + fc + "_" + "convert.shp"
```